# jquery autocmplete set max items

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am going to use the jquery autocomplete plugin and i will to set the max items to display. Searching on google I found that there is the `"max"` option to set at the number of items that I want to show, but it do not work.

I use `jquery-ui-1.8.21` version.

```
$("#test").autocomplete({
     source:myarray,
     max:5
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you read that? I can't find `max` in [autocomplete's documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete) under "options" tab at the bottom.

Although, there's an example how to set the [maximum height](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#maxheight) for better user experience. But if you really want first n elements from that array just use [slice()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) method from pure JavaScript.

Comment: Here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions.

Comment: Later I will try slice method in action.

Comment: [So, as your link says, it's depracated](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) - also look at this autocomplete [migration guide](http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/autocomplete-migration-guide), it says `max` option is gone, so I guess the only way is to use CSS. Keep in mind, slice() will work on array, not on autocomplete's results hence if what you want is scrollable results, then this isn't it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS `.ui-autocomplete { height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;}` By changing the height you can limit the number of items visible to the user.

Comment: If you were using remote (or dynamic) data as source, you could limit the number of rows in the query. In your code you are using an array as a source. Why do you want to limit the number of items ? Don't you want all the items in array to be included in auto-complete?

Comment: Tank you for your help. Now I'm using remote datasource and so I limit rows by server

Comment: Don't forget to set 'delay' and 'minLength' properties for optimized performance. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this way
Into your ajax success function change according this

```
success: function (data) {
      response($.map(data.slice(0,4), function (item) {
           return {
            label: item.name,
            value: item.name
        }
    }));
}
```